# Incorrect placement of background video in div/jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a video playing in the background of a div, however rather than showing behind the text the video is showing as a seperate section above the headline/signup form.

Live example: http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/

**I'd like the text and email signup form to show on top of the video.**

Please note I'm using Bootstrap for a responsive design (video hidden on tablets/mobiles).

I'd like a video to play in the background of my jumbotron.

With full width and a height of 100% of the browser window (more content below when scrolled), this worked for an image but is having issues now.

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron {
color: white;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
height:500px
}


    html,body {height:100%;}
.special,.special .jumbotron 
{height:100%;
width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
}

.fullscreen-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    height: 300%;
    top: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .fullscreen-bg {
    background: url('../img/videoframe.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
  }

  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="fullscreen-bg"></div>
<div class="container special">
<video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">

        <source src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/vid/people-with-no-money-worries.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
</div></div>


  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="h1extrapadding hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>  <h1 class="boldme">Aged 20-30 & frustrated with money?</h1> 
    <div class="greenpromobox">
    <div class="h2extrapadding hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>  <h2 class="boldme">Take our free <b class="jumpstarttext">Jumpstart Your Finances</b> class to<br /> quickly gain control over your finances</h2>


            <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//moneynest.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1&amp;id=299de51b4e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">


                   <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/hand-drawn-arrow.png" id="handarrow" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" alt="arrow"><input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email address" required autofocus>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_299de51b4e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Start Class Now" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->

</div>
</div>

 </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following style to Your .jumbotron

```
margin-bottom: -500px;
z-index: -1;
```

Should help You with this static setup. You can also play with margins values of this elements to layout them correctly.

Comment: Thanks Entio, played around with this in Dev tools and worked well, how do I make this Jumbotron/video take up 100% of the browser window height? E.G. The words and content below "What do you need help with?" show only on scrolling down. I realise now this is probably two questions. My apologies.

Comment: @SamJefferies for the new browsers let's use height: 100vh (100% of viewport height, read more here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: this confuses me somewhat, I didn't realise I was using Viewport units?

Comment: @SamJefferies You aren't, but You can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 .greenpromobox
    {
        top: 40px;
        z-index: 9999999;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 20%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add a class in your div (text and email signup form), I have added `.emailBox` for example and add the following style in that

```
.emailBox {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -585px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

hope this will solve your issue.