# Fill 100% of browser height with Div/Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Jumbotron with an autoplaying background video.

I'd like this to fill 100% of the users browsers window (so the text 'What do you need help with?' only shows on scroll).

How can I make this happen?

Live url: http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron {
color: white;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
height:500px;
margin-bottom: -500px;
z-index: -1;
}


    html,body {height:100%;}
.special,.special .jumbotron 
{height:100%;
width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
}

.fullscreen-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    height: 300%;
    top: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .fullscreen-bg {
    background: url('../img/videoframe.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
  }

  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="fullscreen-bg"></div>
<div class="container special">
<video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">

        <source src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/vid/people-with-no-money-worries.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
</div></div>


  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="h1extrapadding hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>  <h1 class="boldme">Aged 20-30 & frustrated with money?</h1> 
    <div class="greenpromobox">
    <div class="h2extrapadding hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>  <h2 class="boldme">Take our free <b class="jumpstarttext">Jumpstart Your Finances</b> class to<br /> quickly gain control over your finances</h2>


            <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//moneynest.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1&amp;id=299de51b4e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">


                   <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/hand-drawn-arrow.png" id="handarrow" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" alt="arrow"><input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email address" required autofocus>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_299de51b4e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Start Class Now" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->

</div>
</div>

 </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect placement of background video in div/jumbotron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481620/incorrect-placement-of-background-video-in-div-jumbotron)

Answer (score 0):

It will be a combination of making your div's 100% and the Jumbotron 100vh.

Try this:

```
.jumbotron {
color: white;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
height:100vh;
margin-bottom: -500px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

I can't really tell without having a fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the viewport height (`vh`) value on your jumbotron:

```
.jumbotron {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Taking this a bit further, I would use a parent / child selector as opposed to declaring the blanket `.jumbotron` class, i.e.:

```
.parent .jumbotron {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This is because you may want to use the `.jumbotron` on another page and not want it to go `100vh`, but display the default (BootStrap) way.

EDIT - also note your margin-bottom on the jumbotron... you may want to **remove** this from your `.jumbotron` style:

```
margin-bottom: -500px;
```

This is essentially pulling the content below up on top of the video...

Comment: Thanks David, this fills the video (awesome - thanks!) but still keeps the "What do you need help with" in the browser window, should I use Margins to push this down or is there a better way?

Comment: @SamJefferies ah, see EDIT in answer.

Comment: Hi David, I want the content on the video, just not past the green div. I suppose I could add in margin-bottom to all the further divs but it doesn't feel like the right thing to do>?